# How can I get this function to react to the onclick method?

Tags: javascript, canvas, mouseevent

This is the button as is, it currently will get the canvas image and display that image on another canvas.

```
  var formElement2 = document.getElementById("recImage");
     formElement2.addEventListener('click', recImagePressed, false);

     function recImagePressed(e){
         var outputCanvas = document.getElementById("outputCanvas");
         var recr =  canvas2.toDataURL(); 
         outputCtx = outputCanvas.getContext('2d');
         outputCtx.drawImage(canvas2, 0, 0);
         //context2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);<----***
     }  

 //***I need the image to clear when the user clicks, the above is wrong
```

The function that I need to react upon onclick is: (this function has been tested and works if I manually place the png into the function)

```
function init () {  <---------this will be done away with and replaced w/ 
                              onClick ?? <-----------------****
canvas = document.getElementById('canVas');  
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
draw ();
}

function draw() {   <------This is the function that I need to react to mouse event
img = new Image();  
img.src = myPng.png ***---->This is where I need the canvas image<---------------*** 
fr1 = makeFrame(ctx, makeVect(400,0), makeVect(400, 0), makeVect(0, 400));
img.onload = function(){ 
    ctx.save(); 
    newPainter = cornerSplit(imagePainter,5);
    newPainter(fr1);     
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.save();
    newPainter(flipHorizLeft(fr1));
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.save();
    newPainter(flipVertDown(fr1));  
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.save();
    newPainter(flipVertDown(flipHorizLeft(fr1)));   
       }  
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want? If I think you want what you actually want, see my answer, but don't downvote if I misunderstood, please.

Comment: @Tekknolagi---->Pardon my newbyness in js, Im just starting to learn it. I need to do away with the init() function that calls the draw() method and put that call to draw() in the onclick method. Im not sure how to exactly structure your answer with my implementation, that is the spot where Im stuck. Thanks a ton for responding, Im almost done with this project and Ive been banging my head with this last chunk of code.

Comment: as it is now, Im only able to create a canvas image on one page that initializes my drawing canvas, save that image as a png and then place that png into the draw() method that manipulates the image. I need the above button(formElement2) to call the draw() method and then display on the "outputCanvas"

Comment: do i simply replace the img.onload = function(){ } with your answer document.onclick = function(){}.  If so can i then just have this script saved and linked to in my HTML page?

Comment: If you want something to happen when someone first clicks on the page when it's done loading, then what I proposed works

Comment: What element should be clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
formElement2.onclick = function(args, ...) {

}
```